# find the number of even number less than n?

Tags: math, sequence

I have to find the number of even number less than or equal to n having following conditions.
any even number can be written as (2^p)*k where p,k is some constant also it is given that n is also even number so n=(2^q)*m. Now how many even number less than or equal to n will satisfy p>q?

Comment: What are the limits? How big can be `n`?

Comment: value of n can be as big as 10^12

Comment: Are you having a coding problem? If yes, what is the programming language you want to use? I am sure it strongly depends on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my first thought was to implement it with a trivial solution, like the example:

```
const n = 1232;

function getPow(n) {
  let tn = n, twoPow = 0;
  while (tn % 2 === 0) {
    tn /= 2;
    twoPow++;
  }
  return twoPow;
}

const basePow = getPow(n);

let result = 0;
for (let i = 2; i < n; i+=2) {
  const tmpPow = getPow(i);
  if (tmpPow > basePow) {
    result++;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

but then I realize that the solution is all the `M` numbers where `((q+1)^2)*x < n` so this take you to the next formula, that basically is the solution:

```
const n = 1232;

function getPow(n) {
  let tn = n, twoPow = 0;
  while (tn % 2 === 0) {
    tn /= 2;
    twoPow++;
  }
  return twoPow;
}

console.log(Math.floor(n / (Math.pow(2 ,getPow(n) + 1))));
```

because the solution is `O(log n)` any limit fit in time